# How to insert data from dat to sql table?

Tags: sql

I want to insert data from a .dat file to an sql table. But I dont want to use bulk insert.

The dat file looks like this:

```
dd  qwe 3
ss  asd 3
```

How can I do this?

Thanks..

Comment: "But I dont want to use bulk insert." Why not?

Comment: It is not allowed in the project im working on.

Comment: So what is allowed? And why is BULK INSERT not allowed? You need to give us more information to go on here. My boss wants me to drive to CompUSA to pick up an SSD, but he said "no pickup trucks allowed." What do I do?

Comment: @pyram perhaps while you're editing the question you can reword from "I don't want to use bulk insert" to "Unfortunately, the constraints of the project eliminate the possibility of bulk insert."

Comment: Everything else is allowed. What's not allowed is: bulk insert, and i guess other functions at that same level.-.............Knowing this, which other options do i have?

Comment: @pyram is this homework?  seems strange that you wouldn't be allowed to use BULK INSERT.

Comment: So is this a one time operation, or something your "friend" will have to do over and over again with different dat files?

Comment: So then read the file one line at a time and do a bunch of single row inserts.  What's stopping you?

Comment: Also, why are you referring to a person as a "figure"?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to copy the contents of the file into Excel, add proper delimiters and commas in the first row, using new columns between each data column, and then drag down to the end of the data rows in order to repeat that for each row. Copy and paste the entire populated grid into a query window, search and replace tabs with empty space, and voila!

[image]

If using SQL Server 2012, there is more powerful region editing that you can use. For example you can copy plain text into the query editor, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to highlight multiple rows and enter text on all rows at the same time:

[image]

There are other solutions such as BCP, using OPENROWSET with a bulk provider, etc. but your vague "not allowed" requirement makes it impossible to guess if any of those alternatives will be allowed either.

Comment: ...or you could use a scripting language to read the file and programatically generate the `insert` statements.

Comment: @JackManey true, I was trying to keep it simple, in case the "friend" doesn't know VBScript or C# or PowerShell...